# Creating a multiple-level MemberExpression

Tags: c#, linq

I know how to create a `MemberExpression` e.g. `entity.Property`

```
// Expression: "entity"
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "entity");

// Expression: "entity.Property"
var property = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, entityType.GetProperty(propertyName));
```

But I want to create a `MemberExpression` that accesses a subproperty e.g `entity.Property.SubProperty`

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "entity");

   // Expression: "entity.Property"
   var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
   var subProperty = Expression.Property(property, subPropertyName);
```